# number of sequences with constrains and orders

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I want to know if I have $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2\}$ and I want to make sure that I consider all possible sequences with these constraints:
$a_2$ cannot be before $a_1$, and $a_3$ cannot be before $a_2$. 
$b_2$ cannot be before $b_1$. 
for this case of 3 and 2 elements, possible sequences are:

```
a1,a2,a3,b1,b2
a1,a2,b1,b2,a3
a1,a2,b1,a3,b2

a1,b1,a2,a3,b2
a1,b1,b2,a2,a3
a1,b1,a2,b2,a3

b1,b2,a1,a2,a3

b1,a1,a2,a3,b2
b1,a1,b2,a2,a3
b1,a1,a2,b2,a3
```

Is there any mathematical representation of other combination of n & m elements in two given initial sequences?

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneously "*choose*" which spaces are occupied by the $a$'s.  Then, the remaining spaces will be occupied by the $b$'s.  The way you've phrased the problem it sounds as though all of the $a$'s must appear in increasing order and all of the $b$'s must appear in increasing order.  As a result, whichever spaces chosen for the $a$'s will have the $a$'s in increasing order and similarly for the $b$'s.

Counting how many ways there are to choose which spaces were occupied by the $a$'s in the first place, we turn to a particularly powerful tool in counting known as [Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ counts (*among many other things*) the number of ways you can select $r$ objects out of $n$ distinct objects where order of the selection doesn't matter.  Alternatively worded, it counts the number of subsets of size $r$ of a set with size $n$.

We have $n+m$ total spaces, and we want to choose $n$ of them to be occupied by the $a$'s, giving a total of:

> $\binom{n+m}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Set the elements of A first, so you have the list $a1,a2,a3$.
Next, insert the elements of B (ignore order for now).
The first element can go into one of 4 spaces, and the second can go into one of 5 spaces. Therefore there are $4\cdot5=20$ ways you can create the list. However, half of these will have the elements of b in the wrong order. Therefore there are $20/2=10$ ways, as you have shown.

See if you can generalize for N elements of a and M elements of b following this logic.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it works!

Comment: What makes you say that?